# Wordpress define custom fields list

Tags: wordpress

How can I define default custom fields list in wordpress?

I want to give users ability to choose custom fields from list when they create or edit post in admin. On that coustom fields I will base design and make different styles when users choose "youtube" or "image". It's impossible to find any solution for that simple problem in web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress takes existing custom fields and presents them in a select box. So, once you've created a custom field once on one page it will be available on all pages in the WP Admin. Just click "Enter New" about the Custom Field select box and it will allow you to enter in a new meta key.

**More Technical**

Custom Fields are stored in your Metadata database table, whereas the custom field name is the meta_key and the custom field value is the meta_value.

When an edit page loads it take a grouping of all custom fields (minus fields that are used for internal use) and presents them in the select drop down.

**Retrieving**

Retrieving a custom field would be as follows:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID,"CUSTOM FIELD NAME",true);
```

**Predefined Custom Fields**

WordPress offers a popular plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) that allows you to create different types of custom fields with preset values. This helps content editors to choose the appropriate value attached with the appropriate custom field.

Comment: ok but my problem is that I learning creating themes ... so I need to define default custom fields for people who will buy this template ... maybe it's impossible I don't know, I'm just starting...

Comment: ok I just reload. I never use ready scripts but as I see this is an armagedon :) When I create my own app in RoR I just put new table and that all ... here, some plugins for that simple thing.... :)) wow I'm surprised that people use that :)